# run loop atleast one time in Smarty

Tags: php, loops, smarty, do-while

How can I run my loop at least one time in Smarty ?

If I use `for` and `to` is `0` my loop never will be run !

I have a form and I want to show at least one time but if `fieldCounter` have a value more than 1 the loop should run until `fieldCounter` value.

```
{for $start=1 to $fieldCounter}
<input type="text" name="price{$start}" value="" />
{/for}
```

Is there `do {} while();` in Smarty ?

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.while.tpl

Comment: Make sure that $fieldCounter is >= 1

Comment: @JeffHawthorne smarty `while` function run loop like `while` in PHP, and if my variable is `0` the loop will never run

Comment: then change your condition

Comment: @JeffHawthorne You cannot do this with changing condition

Comment: sure you can. you can put an || in there for 0, and if you want an action that only happens for 1, you can put an if/else inside your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max()`:

```
{assign var=_to value=max($fieldCounter,1)}
{for $start=1 to $_to}
<input type="text" name="price{$start}" value="" />
{/for}
```

Now `$_to` will always be at least `1`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try smartys {forelse}.

```
{for $start=1 to $fieldCounter}
  <input type="text" name="price{$start}" value="" />
{forelse}
  <input type="text" name="price1" value="" />
{/for}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl